# ¿Cómo sumo totales de un resultado que saqué a base de un SUM en SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

Necesito realizar la suma final de unos valores que ya saqué a traves de una suma, es decir necesito sacar el total del total.

```
select
ISNULL (sum(reng_fac.reng_neto),0) as TOTAL_VENTAS,
ROUND(((prec_vta3-art.prec_vta2)/prec_vta3)*100,2) AS MARGEN,
ART.co_lin AS LINEA,
ART.co_subl AS SUBLINEA


from art
full join reng_fac
on art.co_art = reng_fac.co_art

WHERE art.prec_vta1 != '0' 
and   art.prec_vta2 != '0' 
and   art.prec_vta3 != '0' 
and   art.cos_pro_un != '0' 

group by 
reng_fac.fec_lote, art.co_art, 
art.art_des, art.prec_vta1, 
art.prec_vta2, art.prec_vta3, 
art.stock_act, art.cos_pro_un, 
co_lin, co_subl

ORDER BY FECHA
```

Lo que quiero es realizar una columna nueva que se llame Tot_final que me traiga el total de todos los productos de la columna ToTal_VENTAS

Intenté agregar esto:

```
select 
sum((select(sum(tot_neto)) from factura)) as tot_final
from factura
```

Pero no funcionó

¡Ayuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes guardar los datos de la consulta en una tabla temporal:

```
select
    ISNULL (sum(reng_fac.reng_neto),0) as TOTAL_VENTAS,
    ROUND(((prec_vta3-art.prec_vta2)/prec_vta3)*100,2) AS MARGEN,
    ART.co_lin AS LINEA,
    ART.co_subl AS SUBLINEA
    
    INTO #temptable
    
    from art
    full join reng_fac
    on art.co_art = reng_fac.co_art
    
    WHERE art.prec_vta1 != '0' 
    and   art.prec_vta2 != '0' 
    and   art.prec_vta3 != '0' 
    and   art.cos_pro_un != '0' 
    
    group by 
    reng_fac.fec_lote, art.co_art, 
    art.art_des, art.prec_vta1, 
    art.prec_vta2, art.prec_vta3, 
    art.stock_act, art.cos_pro_un, 
    co_lin, co_subl
```

Se guarda el total en una variable:

```
declare @total decimal(10,2) = select sum(TOTAL_VENTAS) from #temptable;
```

Se hace la consulta final

```
select *, @total as tot_total
from #temptable order by fecha
```